# Loading a .txt file and breaking lines with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I currently have hundreds of .txt files I am using a function to grab and load into a DIV, though as is parses the file it doesn't appear to be accounting for format or line breaks. I have tried both the .split() & .replace() to no avail, I have tried assigning a separate string variable to load it into then applying the split/replace, as well as using split/replace directly on the file before loading it, and lastly as apart of the string variable in the .load()

I would like it to at least brek all the correct lines in the .text file this is what I am using:

```
var clickedLink = "";
var fileOpen = "";

$(".load-content").click(function() {
    clickedLink = $(this).attr("title");
    fileOpen = "txt/" + clickedLink;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.load-content').click(function() {
        $('#mainLetter').load(fileOpen);
    });
});
```

This works great for getting the info from the link and loading it onto the page but trying combinations of `.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');` & `.split("\n").join("<br />")` I am having no luck in getting the .txt file looking half way normal on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried just using a `<pre>` tag

Comment: You can use  var str = $("#mainLetter").val();
if( str.indexOf(" ") !== -1 )
{
   $("#mainLetter").css("display","block");
}

Comment: @HemaNandagopal That won't do anything to the content inside of `#mainLetter`.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out why exactly it is I have never heard of a <pre> tag! Yes, I changed the <div id="mainLetter"> to <pre id="MainLetter"> & it works!!